# Print a msg from a Turtlebot3 subscriber

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I am just trying to print a msg that is subscribed from the cmd_vel_rc100 message. Here is some of the code:

```
def moving(self):
        self.pub_cmd_vel = rospy.Publisher('cmd_vel', Twist, queue_size=5)
        while self.finish:
            vel_cmd = Twist()
            vel_cmd_received = Twist()
            vel_cmd.linear.x = 0
            self.pub_cmd_vel.publish(vel_cmd)
            vel_cmd_received = rospy.Subscriber('cmd_vel_rc100', Twist, queue_size=5)
            print vel_cmd_received
            self.finish = False
```

When I run the node, I see the following in the terminal for the cmd_vel_rc100:

```
<rospy.topics.Subscriber object at 0x7fd7a0436d50>
```

Normally, the node must be of type Twist(). My question is now, why don´t I see the normal Twist message?

Thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/331177/print-a-msg-from-a-turtlebot3-subscriber/) by [Tima1995](https://answers.ros.org/users/42102/tima1995/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2019-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to use a different method to receive just a single message without a callback as you're trying to in your code. The [rospy.wait_for_message()](https://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/rospy/html/rospy.client-module.html#wait_for_message) will do what you expect, blocking execution until a message is received and returning that message.

A `rospy.Subscriber` object is used when you want to register a callback function to receive messages whenever the arrive on a topic. You normally create it once when your node is created and destroy it when it closes. This is described in the [tutorial here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29#rospy_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingPublisherSubscriber.Writing_the_Subscriber_Node).

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tima1995](https://answers.ros.org/users/42102/tima1995/) on 2019-08-21**:
Worked well, thanks :)